# How do I calculate the derivative of $x|x|$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I know that $$f(x)=x\cdot|x|$$ have no derivative at $$x=0$$ but how do I calculate it's derivative for the rest of the points?
When I  calculate for $$x>0$$ I get that $$f'(x) = 2x $$
but for $$ x < 0 $$ I can't seem to find a way to solve the limit. As this is homework please don't put the answer straight forward.

Comment: **Hint:** what is $|x|$ if $x<0$?

Comment: I know that it's -x but I still can't get further... I'm stuck with  a big polynom

Comment: I believe you have a derivative at $x=0$.

Comment: Do you know the following characterization, which is the root of linear approximation: $f$ is differentiable at $0$ with derivative $f'(0)$ if and only if $f(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+x\epsilon(x)$ with $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\epsilon (x)=0$? In your case, $\epsilon(x)=|x|$ and $f(0)=f'(0)=0$. Here is a reference: http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/ira/cont/proofs/diffaprx.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, draw a picture. Second, make a guess. Third, confirm your guess.

[image]

Hmm, looks like $x \mapsto x^2$ for $x \geq 0$ and $x \mapsto -x^2$ for $x \leq 0$. Indeed $f(x) = x^2$ for $x >0 $, so $f'(x) = 2 x$ when $x > 0$. Similarly, $f(x) = -x^2$ when $x <0$, so 
$f'(x) = -2x$ for $x <0$.

The only issue is $x=0$. Looking at the picture, and indeed, looking at the limiting value for $x \downarrow 0$ and $x \uparrow 0$ suggests that if $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$, then $f'(0) = 0$.

So, working with this guess, we try
$$|f(x)-f(0) - 0.x| = |(x|x|)-0 -0.x| = |x|^2$$
If $x\neq 0$, we have $\frac{|f(x)-f(0) - 0.x|}{|x|} = |x|$, from which it follows that 
$f'(0) = 0$. Formally.

To wrap up,  notice that $f'(x) = 2|x|$.

Working without the intuition is difficult. For me, drawing a rough picture provides much of the intuition. If the intuition is sound, then it is often straightforward to formalize the result.

Comment: I'm not supposed to draw the graph, just calculate the derivative.

Comment: Do the extra work.

Comment: But how can I formally prove with tools I'm not allowed to use?

Comment: I think the idea is that the picture can help you figure out what answer you're supposed to get; it might not end up being the method you ultimately use in your written answer.

Comment: You can turn it into a slightly more formal proof by observing that the definition of the derivative of a function at a point only depends on its values around that point. So if two functions agree near that point, they have the same derivative there. For example, since $f(x)=x^2$ for $x>0$, the derivative of $f$ and the derivative of $x\mapsto x^2$ are equal at any point $x$ with $x>0$.

Comment: Yes, I should have made a bigger deal about the point that @user108903 has elaborated: If $f(x) = g(x) $ in a neighborhood of $\hat{x}$ and $g$ is differentiable at $\hat{x}$, then so is $f$, and $f'(\hat{x}) = g'(\hat{x})$.

Comment: @Georgey Draw it in your mind.

Comment: @jinawee THANKS! I was waiting for this answer to be written for over a year.

Answer (score 11):

- For $x \ge 0$ you have $f(x)=x \times |x| = x \times x = x^2$
- For $x \le 0$ you have $f(x)=x \times |x| = x \times (-x) = -x^2$

so you can calculate the derivative when $x \gt 0$ and the derivative when $x \lt 0$ in the usual way.

You are wrong when you say there is no derivative when $x=0$.

Answer (score 6):

There's a great trick that you can use. Notice that for all real $x \neq 0$ you have $|x| \equiv \sqrt{x^2}$.

If you want to know the derivative of $x|x|$ away from $x=0$ then consider $x\sqrt{x^2}$. Using the chain rule and the product rule we can show that, assuming $x \neq 0$,

$$\frac{d}{dx}x|x| \equiv \frac{d}{dx} x\sqrt{x^2} = \sqrt{x^2} + \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2}} \equiv |x| + \frac{x^2}{|x|} \, . $$

Moreover, this little trick works in many more situations. For example, consider $f(|x|)$. Provided we stay away from $x = 0$, $g(|x|) \equiv g(\sqrt{x^2})$ and so:

$$\frac{d}{dx} g(|x|) = \frac{x}{|x|}\frac{d}{dx}g(|x|) \, . $$

Answer (score 3):

When $x<0$ replace $|x|$ by $-x$ (since that is what it is equal to) in the formula for the function and proceed.

Please note as well that the function $f(x)=x\cdot |x|$ does have a derivative at $0$.

Comment: so is $f(x)' = 2x$ for $x >= 0$ and $f(x)' = -2x$ for $x < 0$?

Comment: @Eran Strictly speaking, $f(x)$ is a *number* and so $f(x)' = 0$ for all $x$. It's better to write $f'(x)$, i.e. $f'$ evaluated at $x$.

Comment: @Fly by Night Even more strictly speaking, f(x) is a number and so it is not a function and thus can't be differentiated at all.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Of course it can. You can think of it as a constant function if you like.

Comment: Not if you are being strict about the notation. Otherwise, you can also *think* of f(x)' as the derivative of f at x. Either f(x)' has no meaning (if you want to be strict), or you assign to it some plausible meaning. There are at least two (inconsistent) ways to do the latter.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** If $x\gt 0$ we are looking at $x^2$, easy. If $x\lt 0$, we are looking at $-x^2$, easy. For $x=0$, use the **definition** of the derivative.

So at $0$ we want $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\,\dots$,

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$$
\color{#00f}{\large\totald{\pars{x\verts{x}}}{x}}
=\verts{x} + x\sgn\pars{x} = \verts{x} + \verts{x}
= \color{#00f}{\large 2\verts{x}}
$$